# How to find irq number for I²C device?

Tags: c, embedded, embedded-linux, i2c, irq

I'm trying to connect an I2C device (MPU6050 accelerometer) with this code:

```
#define MPUIRQ_GPIO           ?  // the var I would like to know
#include <mach/i2c.h>
#include <mach/irqs-sun7i.h>
static struct i2c_board_info sun7i_i2c_platform_device[] __initdata = {
        {
            I2C_BOARD_INFO("mpu6050", 0x68),        
            .irq = (NR_IRQS + MPUIRQ_GPIO),    
            .platform_data = (void *)&gyro_platform_data,
        },
    };
```

The original line is:

```
.irq = (IH_GPIO_BASE + MPUIRQ_GPIO),
```

but I have to find the new names of the vars.
So, I'm sure that `IH_GPIO_BASE` = `NR_IRQS`, according to **/include/mach/irqs-sun7i.h**, but I can not find `MPUIRQ_GPIO`

The irqs-sun7i.h file:

```
#ifndef __MACH_IRQS_AW_H
#define __MACH_IRQS_AW_H

#define AW_IRQ_GIC_START        32

/*
 * sgi and ppi irq sources
 */
#define IRQ_SGI0            0
#define IRQ_SGI1            1
#define IRQ_SGI2            2
#define IRQ_SGI3            3
#define IRQ_SGI4            4
#define IRQ_SGI5            5
#define IRQ_SGI6            6
#define IRQ_SGI7            7
#define IRQ_SGI8            8
#define IRQ_SGI9            9
#define IRQ_SGI10           10
#define IRQ_SGI11           11
#define IRQ_SGI12           12
#define IRQ_SGI13           13
#define IRQ_SGI14           14
#define IRQ_SGI15           15
#define IRQ_PPI0            0
#define IRQ_PPI1            1
#define IRQ_PPI2            2
#define IRQ_PPI3            3
#define IRQ_PPI4            4
#define IRQ_PPI5            5
#define IRQ_PPI6            6
#define IRQ_PPI7            7
#define IRQ_PPI8            8
#define IRQ_PPI9            9
#define IRQ_PPI10           10
#define IRQ_PPI11           11
#define IRQ_PPI12           12
#define IRQ_PPI13           13
#define IRQ_PPI14           14
#define IRQ_PPI15           15

/*
 * AW on-board gic irq sources
 */
#if defined(CONFIG_AW_FPGA_PLATFORM)
/* NOTE: maybe err, need redifine irqs number on sun7i fpga */
#define AW_IRQ_NMI          (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 0 )    /* NMI    */
#define AW_IRQ_UART0        (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 1 )    /* UART0  */
#define AW_IRQ_UART1        (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 2 )    /* UART1  */
#define AW_IRQ_UART2        (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 3 )    /* UART2  */
#define AW_IRQ_UART3        (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 4 )    /* UART3  */
#define AW_IRQ_IR0          (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 2 )    /* IR0 (on fpga, irq2 is shared by IR0(37), twi0(39), keypad(53), can(58), GPIO(60), ps2-0(94)) */
#define AW_IRQ_IR1          (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 6 )    /* IR1    */
#define AW_IRQ_TWI0         (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 2 )  //  /* TWI0 (on fpga, irq2 is shared by IR0(37), twi0(39), keypad(53), can(58), GPIO(60), ps2-0(94)) */
#define AW_IRQ_TWI1         (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 8 )    /* TWI1   */
#define AW_IRQ_TWI2         (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 9 )  //  /* TWI2   */
#define AW_IRQ_SPI0         (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 15)    /* SPI0   */
#define AW_IRQ_SPI1         (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 11)    /* SPI1   */
#define AW_IRQ_SPI2         (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 12)    /* SPI2   */
#define AW_IRQ_SPDIF        (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 3 )    /* SPDIF (on fpga, irq3 is shared by spdif(45), ac97(46), ts(47), iis(48), ple(98)) */
#define AW_IRQ_AC97         (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 3 )    /* AC97 (on fpga, irq3 is shared by spdif(45), ac97(46), ts(47), iis(48), ple(98)) */
#define AW_IRQ_TS           (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 3 )    /* TS (on fpga, irq3 is shared by spdif(45), ac97(46), ts(47), iis(48), ple(98)) */
#define AW_IRQ_IIS          (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 3 )    /* IIS (on fpga, irq3 is shared by spdif(45), ac97(46), ts(47), iis(48), ple(98)) */
#define AW_IRQ_UART4        (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 17)    /* UART4  */
#define AW_IRQ_UART5        (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 18)    /* UART5  */
#define AW_IRQ_UART6        (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 19)    /* UART6  */
#define AW_IRQ_UART7        (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 20)    /* UART7  */
#define AW_IRQ_KEYPAD       (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 2 )    /* KEYPAD (on fpga, irq2 is shared by IR0(37), twi0(39), keypad(53), can(58), GPIO(60), ps2-0(94)) */
#define AW_IRQ_TIMER0       (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 4 )    /* Timer0 */
#define AW_IRQ_TIMER1       (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 5 )    /* Timer1 (on fpga, irq5 is shared by timer1(55), hstimer(113)) */
#define AW_IRQ_TIMER2       (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 6 )  //  /* Timer2 / alarm / watchdog  */
#define AW_IRQ_TIMER3       (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 25)    /* Timer3 */
#define AW_IRQ_CAN          (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 2 )    /* CAN (on fpga, irq2 is shared by IR0(37), twi0(39), keypad(53), can(58), GPIO(60), ps2-0(94)) */
#define AW_IRQ_DMA          (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 7 )    /* DMA irq on fpga   */
#define AW_IRQ_GPIO         (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 2 )  //  /* GPIO (on fpga, irq2 is shared by IR0(37), twi0(39), keypad(53), can(58), GPIO(60), ps2-0(94)) */
#define AW_IRQ_TOUCH_PANEL  (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 8 )    /* touch pannel  */
#define AW_IRQ_AUDIO_COEC   (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 8 )    /* AUDIO COEC  */
#define AW_IRQ_LRADC        (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 8 )    /* LRADC  */
#define AW_IRQ_MMC0         (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 9 )    /* MMC0   */
#define AW_IRQ_MMC1         (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 33)    /* MMC1   */
#define AW_IRQ_MMC2         (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 10)    /* MMC2   */
#define AW_IRQ_MMC3         (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 35)    /* MMC3   */
#define AW_IRQ_MS           (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 10)    /* MS  */
#define AW_IRQ_NAND         (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 11)    /* NAND  */
#define AW_IRQ_USB0         (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 12)    /* USB0  */
#define AW_IRQ_USB1         (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 13)    /* USB1  */
#define AW_IRQ_USB2         (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 14)    /* USB2  */
#define AW_IRQ_SCR          (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 15)    /* SCR   */
#define AW_IRQ_CSI0         (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 16)    /* CSI0  */
#define AW_IRQ_CSI1         (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 14)    /* CSI1  */
#define AW_IRQ_LCDC0        (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 17)    /* LCDC0 */
#define AW_IRQ_LCDC1        (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 18)    /* LCDC1 */
#define AW_IRQ_MP           (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 19)    /* MP    */
#define AW_IRQ_DE0          (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 20)    /* DE-FE0 / DE-BE0 */
#define AW_IRQ_DE1          (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 21)    /* DE-FE1 / DE-BE1 */
#define AW_IRQ_PMU          (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 22)    /* PMU   */
#define AW_IRQ_SPI3         (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 50)    /* SPI3  */

#define AW_IRQ_PATA         (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 22)    /* PATA  */
#define AW_IRQ_VE           (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 24)    /* VE    */
#define AW_IRQ_SS           (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 24)    /* SS    */
#define AW_IRQ_EMAC         (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 15)    /* EMAC  */
#define AW_IRQ_SATA         (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 22)    /* sata  */
#define AW_IRQ_GPS          (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 24)    /* GPS   */
#define AW_IRQ_HDMI         (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 23)    /* HDMI  */
#define AW_IRQ_TVE_0_1      (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 15)    /* TV encoder 0/1 interrupt  */
#define AW_IRQ_ACE          (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 24)    /* ACE   */
#define AW_IRQ_TVD          (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 14)    /* TVD   */
#define AW_IRQ_PS2_0        (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 2 )    /* PS2_0(on fpga, irq2 is shared by IR0(37), twi0(39), keypad(53), can(58), GPIO(60), ps2-0(94)) */
#define AW_IRQ_PS2_1        (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 63)    /* PS2_1 */
#define AW_IRQ_USB3         (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 15)    /* USB3  */
#define AW_IRQ_USB4         (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 16)    /* USB4  */
#define AW_IRQ_PLE_PERFMU   (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 3 )    /* PLE_PERFMU (on fpga, irq3 is shared by spdif(45), ac97(46), ts(47), iis(48), ple(98)) */
#define AW_IRQ_TIMER4       (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 67)    /* TIMER4  */
#define AW_IRQ_TIMER5       (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 68)    /* TIMER5  */
#define AW_IRQ_GPU_GP       (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 25)    /* GPU_GP  */
#define AW_IRQ_GPU_GPMMU    (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 26)    /* GPU_GPMMU */
#define AW_IRQ_GPU_PP0      (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 27)    /* GPU_PP0  */
#define AW_IRQ_GPU_PPMMU0   (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 28)    /* GPU_PPMMU0 */
#define AW_IRQ_GPU_PMU      (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 29)    /* GPU_PMU  */
#define AW_IRQ_GPU_PP1      (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 30)    /* GPU_PP1  */
#define AW_IRQ_GPU_PPMMU1   (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 31)    /* GPU_PPMMU1 */
#define AW_IRQ_GPU_RSV0     (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 76)    /* GPU_RSV0  */
#define AW_IRQ_GPU_RSV1     (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 77)    /* GPU_RSV1  */
#define AW_IRQ_GPU_RSV2     (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 78)    /* GPU_RSV2  */
#define AW_IRQ_GPU_RSV3     (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 79)    /* GPU_RSV3  */
#define AW_IRQ_GPU_RSV4     (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 80)    /* GPU_RSV4  */
#define AW_IRQ_HSTIMER0     (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 5 )    /* hr-timer0 */
#define AW_IRQ_HSTIMER1     (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 82)    /* hr-timer1 */
#define AW_IRQ_HSTIMER2     (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 83)    /* hr-timer2 */
#define AW_IRQ_HSTIMER3     (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 84)    /* hr-timer3 */
#define AW_IRQ_GMAC         (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 15)    /* GMAC  */
#elif defined(CONFIG_AW_ASIC_PLATFORM)
#define AW_IRQ_NMI          (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 0 )    /* NMI    */
#define AW_IRQ_UART0        (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 1 )    /* UART0  */
#define AW_IRQ_UART1        (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 2 )    /* UART1  */
#define AW_IRQ_UART2        (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 3 )    /* UART2  */
#define AW_IRQ_UART3        (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 4 )    /* UART3  */
#define AW_IRQ_IR0          (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 5 )    /* IR0    */
#define AW_IRQ_IR1          (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 6 )    /* IR1    */
#define AW_IRQ_TWI0         (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 7 )    /* TWI0   */
#define AW_IRQ_TWI1         (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 8 )    /* TWI1   */
#define AW_IRQ_TWI2         (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 9 )    /* TWI2   */
#define AW_IRQ_SPI0         (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 10)    /* SPI0   */
#define AW_IRQ_SPI1         (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 11)    /* SPI1   */
#define AW_IRQ_SPI2         (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 12)    /* SPI2   */
#define AW_IRQ_SPDIF        (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 13)    /* SPDIF  */
#define AW_IRQ_AC97         (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 14)    /* AC97   */
#define AW_IRQ_TS           (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 15)    /* TS     */
#define AW_IRQ_IIS          (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 16)    /* IIS    */
#define AW_IRQ_UART4        (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 17)    /* UART4  */
#define AW_IRQ_UART5        (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 18)    /* UART5  */
#define AW_IRQ_UART6        (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 19)    /* UART6  */
#define AW_IRQ_UART7        (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 20)    /* UART7  */
#define AW_IRQ_KEYPAD       (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 21)    /* KEYPAD */
#define AW_IRQ_TIMER0       (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 22)    /* Timer0 */
#define AW_IRQ_TIMER1       (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 23)    /* Timer1 */
#define AW_IRQ_TIMER2       (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 24)    /* Timer2 / alarm / watchdog  */
#define AW_IRQ_TIMER3       (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 25)    /* Timer3 */
#define AW_IRQ_CAN          (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 26)    /* CAN    */
#define AW_IRQ_DMA          (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 27)    /* DMA    */
#define AW_IRQ_GPIO         (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 28)    /* GPIO    */
#define AW_IRQ_TOUCH_PANEL  (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 29)    /* touch pannel  */
#define AW_IRQ_AUDIO_COEC   (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 30)    /* AUDIO COEC  */
#define AW_IRQ_LRADC        (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 31)    /* LRADC  */
#define AW_IRQ_MMC0         (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 32)    /* MMC0   */
#define AW_IRQ_MMC1         (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 33)    /* MMC1   */
#define AW_IRQ_MMC2         (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 34)    /* MMC2   */
#define AW_IRQ_MMC3         (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 35)    /* MMC3   */
#define AW_IRQ_MS           (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 36)    /* External NMI  */
#define AW_IRQ_NAND         (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 37)    /* NAND  */
#define AW_IRQ_USB0         (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 38)    /* USB0  */
#define AW_IRQ_USB1         (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 39)    /* USB1  */
#define AW_IRQ_USB2         (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 40)    /* USB2  */
#define AW_IRQ_SCR          (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 41)    /* SCR   */
#define AW_IRQ_CSI0         (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 42)    /* CSI0  */
#define AW_IRQ_CSI1         (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 43)    /* CSI1  */
#define AW_IRQ_LCDC0        (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 44)    /* LCDC0 */
#define AW_IRQ_LCDC1        (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 45)    /* LCDC1 */
#define AW_IRQ_MP           (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 46)    /* MP    */
#define AW_IRQ_DE0          (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 47)    /* DE-FE0 / DE-BE0 */
#define AW_IRQ_DE1          (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 48)    /* DE-FE1 / DE-BE1 */
#define AW_IRQ_PMU          (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 49)    /* PMU   */
#define AW_IRQ_SPI3         (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 50)    /* SPI3  */

#define AW_IRQ_PATA         (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 52)    /* PATA  */
#define AW_IRQ_VE           (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 53)    /* VE    */
#define AW_IRQ_SS           (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 54)    /* SS    */
#define AW_IRQ_EMAC         (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 55)    /* EMAC  */
#define AW_IRQ_SATA         (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 56)    /* sata  */
#define AW_IRQ_GPS          (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 57)    /* GPS   */
#define AW_IRQ_HDMI         (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 58)    /* HDMI  */
#define AW_IRQ_TVE_0_1      (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 59)    /* TV encoder 0/1 interrupt  */
#define AW_IRQ_ACE          (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 60)    /* ACE   */
#define AW_IRQ_TVD          (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 61)    /* TVD   */
#define AW_IRQ_PS2_0        (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 62)    /* PS2_0 */
#define AW_IRQ_PS2_1        (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 63)    /* PS2_1 */
#define AW_IRQ_USB3         (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 64)    /* USB3  */
#define AW_IRQ_USB4         (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 65)    /* USB4  */
#define AW_IRQ_PLE_PERFMU   (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 66)    /* PLE_PERFMU */
#define AW_IRQ_TIMER4       (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 67)    /* TIMER4  */
#define AW_IRQ_TIMER5       (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 68)    /* TIMER5  */
#define AW_IRQ_GPU_GP       (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 69)    /* GPU_GP  */
#define AW_IRQ_GPU_GPMMU    (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 70)    /* GPU_GPMMU */
#define AW_IRQ_GPU_PP0      (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 71)    /* GPU_PP0  */
#define AW_IRQ_GPU_PPMMU0   (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 72)    /* GPU_PPMMU0 */
#define AW_IRQ_GPU_PMU      (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 73)    /* GPU_PMU  */
#define AW_IRQ_GPU_PP1      (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 74)    /* GPU_PP1  */
#define AW_IRQ_GPU_PPMMU1   (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 75)    /* GPU_PPMMU1 */
#define AW_IRQ_GPU_RSV0     (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 76)    /* GPU_RSV0  */
#define AW_IRQ_GPU_RSV1     (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 77)    /* GPU_RSV1  */
#define AW_IRQ_GPU_RSV2     (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 78)    /* GPU_RSV2  */
#define AW_IRQ_GPU_RSV3     (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 79)    /* GPU_RSV3  */
#define AW_IRQ_GPU_RSV4     (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 80)    /* GPU_RSV4  */
#define AW_IRQ_HSTIMER0     (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 81)    /* hr-timer0 */
#define AW_IRQ_HSTIMER1     (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 82)    /* hr-timer1 */
#define AW_IRQ_HSTIMER2     (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 83)    /* hr-timer2 */
#define AW_IRQ_HSTIMER3     (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 84)    /* hr-timer3 */
#define AW_IRQ_GMAC         (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 85)    /* GMAC  */
#define AW_IRQ_TWI3         (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 88 )   /* TWI3   */
#define AW_IRQ_TWI4         (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 89)    /* TWI4   */
#else
#error "ERROR: please select a valid platform\n"
#endif

/*
 * GIC
 */
#define NR_IRQS           (AW_IRQ_GIC_START + 128)
#define MAX_GIC_NR        1


#endif    /* __MACH_IRQS_AW_H */
```

The /proc/interrupts file of my system is:

```
           CPU0       CPU1       
 29:      53802      39462       GIC  arch_timer
 30:          0          0       GIC  arch_timer
 32:          0          0       GIC  axp_mfd
 33:          1          0       GIC  sw_serial0
 39:      10944          0       GIC  sun7i-i2c.0
 40:         14          0       GIC  sun7i-i2c.1
 41:          8          0       GIC  sun7i-i2c.2
 54:          6          0       GIC  timer0
 56:          0          0       GIC  sunxi-rtc alarm
 59:          0          0       GIC  dma_irq
 60:          0          0       GIC  gpio_irq
 63:          0          0       GIC  swkbd
 64:     498179          0       GIC  sunxi-mmc
 67:         65          0       GIC  sunxi-mmc
 69:          0          0       GIC  nand_dev
 71:       9435          0       GIC  ehci_hcd:usb2
 72:      17547          0       GIC  ehci_hcd:usb4
 76:      43889          0       GIC  dev_name
 78:          0          0       GIC  g2d
 79:      21896          0       GIC  dev_name
 80:          0          0       GIC  dev_name
 85:          0          0       GIC  cedar_dev
 88:          0          0       GIC  sw_ahci
 96:          0          0       GIC  ohci_hcd:usb3
101:       6965          0       GIC  mali_gp_irq_handlers
102:          0          0       GIC  mali_mmu_irq_handlers
103:       6949          0       GIC  mali_pp_irq_handlers
104:          0          0       GIC  mali_mmu_irq_handlers
106:       6949          0       GIC  mali_pp_irq_handlers
107:          0          0       GIC  mali_mmu_irq_handlers
117:          5          0       GIC  eth0
120:          8          0       GIC  sun7i-i2c.3
121:          0          0       GIC  sun7i-i2c.4
IPI0:          0          0  Timer broadcast interrupts
IPI1:      55349     250299  Rescheduling interrupts
IPI2:          0          0  Function call interrupts
IPI3:         56         95  Single function call interrupts
IPI4:          0          0  CPU stop interrupts
IPI5:          0          0  CPU backtrace
Err:          0
```

So, what is the equivalent of `MPUIRQ_GPIO` ? I have tried many numbers, but the dmesg says this:

```
[   11.961510] inv_mpu_iio: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[   11.963874] inv-mpu-iio 2-0068: probe
[   11.963914] inv-mpu-iio 2-0068: Unable to read axis_map_x
[   11.969998] i2c i2c-1: inv_mpu_probe failed -38
[   11.975080] inv-mpu-iio: probe of 1-0068 failed with error -5
[   11.975436] i2c-core: driver [inv-mpu-iio] registered
```

with

```
# i2cdetect -y 2
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: UU UU UU UU UU UU UU UU -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 68 -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

Comment: Perhaps this helps: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/i2c/instantiating-devices

Comment: I'm not familiar with sun7i , but in irqs-sun7i.h files there is  AW_IRQ_IIS define.

Comment: @alk: this is for omap board, sun7i is a quite different. My reference page is also for omap: http://kernel--tegra.android-source-browsing.googlecode.com/git-history/08f02f8bba6ec3613a3ca3d19e1a07f67739bdd4/drivers/staging/iio/imu/inv_mpu/README
LPs: thanks, I will try.

Comment: @Guillaume If this is for OMAP board, and is "quite different" from sun7i, why are you suing a sun7i header?

Comment: @mjs no, I'm using a sun7i board (A20 orange pi), but my ref is written for omap. I'm trying to 'translate' it to sun7i. But I will try to plug magnetometer (xda and xcl) to see if it's better.

Comment: On AVR32 from Atmel the I2C is called TWI (Two Wire Interface)

Comment: Thanks ʎəʞo uɐɪ, on sun7i it's the same. I'm trying to create node (folders `/sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0` etc) in the `sun7i.rc` file, because no found the solution yet...